# how do i read a properties file from a website with java?

Tags: java, file, properties, web, readfile

I am working on a java program but i need to be able to have all users be able to access it without a properties file that i have. I want a way to host the properties file on a website so the java program clients can access it/ read it/ write to it. Is this possible? If so please explain

Comment: Have you tried __anything__ at all, to achieve your goal? Hint: search for at 'java properties' and 'java url' on google. It's ok if you can't get it right and come here for help, but at least try something on your own before posting a question.

Comment: It is more typical to use a database when clients read and write data.  Properties files are generally for system setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

1. You've got a Java application
2. You're going to distribute the application to users, and users will execute it locally

   ... but ...
3. You simply want your users to be able to access a global properties file from the web.

Is that correct?

If so, simply:

1) read the file with the Java URLConnection/stream class

```
 * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html
```

2) use "properties.load()" as you would any other properties file - just use the URLconnection stream instead of a FileStream

'Hope that helps

PS:

I would definitely have a local properties file - or set reasonable default values - as a backup, in case the user's Internet connection is temporarily down.